# patch panel and switch different sizes

Tags: switch, rackmount, networking

The switch is a DLink 24-port, 14" wide, and the panel is a TRENDnet 24-port, 20" wide.
Do they sell braces for the switch?
What's the best way to mount both to a rack?

Answer (score 1):

20"??? I've never heard of a 20" rack. They're usually 19". Are you measuring the width of the chassis or to between the ends of the brackets.

Certainly D-Link used to provide extension brackets for mounting in a standard rack - they usually come in the same box. I didn't see anything in a quick google - try contacting D-Link directly.

> What's the best way to mount both to a rack?

?
With bolts? The right way up? Not sure what you're asking here.

Comment: this is the patch panel...lists dimension as 20" wide.  http://www.amazon.com/TRENDnet-24-port-Unshielded-Patch-TC-P24C6/dp/B0000AZK72/

Answer (score 0):

Yea your question is sort of vague.. but you will obviously need brackets to rack mount the DLink switch below the patch panel. (And it is more likely 19" since that is pretty standard for rack width)

As for location, generally switches and panels would be at the top above your other hardware.. but you can configure them to whatever works best for your setup/where your cables are.
It is also a good idea to have them facing outward in the back of the rack, since most server NICs are in the back..but again, whatever floats your boat

**You can try a universal kit like this:
https://www.andovercg.com/store/Universal-1U-Server-Rackmount-Rack-Mount-Brackets-p336.html

Comment: this is for a home setup of just the patch panel, switch, and router.  Any recommendations of a small rack to fit just those?